# Sizeof failing in template even though types are all defined

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, sizeof

Ok, I am working with g++ 4.8.2 and have the following (somewhat long) code that gets an error message about an incomplete type.  I have reduced the code to a smaller chunk for inclusion here and can be compiled directly:

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct S
{
  void method(){}
};


template<size_t sz, size_t tot>
class genpool
{
};

template <class T>
class mempool
{
private:
  genpool<sizeof(T), 10*sizeof(T)> p;
};


template <class obj, class mthd>
class functor
{
private:
  static mempool<functor<obj, mthd> > pool;
};

template <class obj, class mthd>
mempool<functor<obj, mthd> > functor<obj, mthd>::pool;

int main()
{
  typedef void (S::*m)();
  typedef functor<S, m> fctr;

  fctr f;
}
```

The compiler error message is:

```
g++ jj.C
jj.C: In instantiation of ‘class mempool<functor<S, void (S::*)()> >’:
jj.C:30:30:   required from ‘class functor<S, void (S::*)()>’
jj.C:37:8:   required from here
jj.C:18:17: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘functor<S, void (S::*)()>’
   genpool<sizeof(T), 10*sizeof(T)> p;
                 ^

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Thu Apr  9 18:50:06
```

Obviously, the template functor is defined above and all the arguments to functor have been explicitly defined.  This seems to imply to me that the sizeof function should be well defined.  Is there something that I am missing here?

--Ron

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the compiler is attempting to instantiate `mempool<>` before it instantiates `functor<>`. This is because the compiler feels it needs to be able to define the static member `functor<>::pool` first before `functor<>` itself is considered fully defined.

A workaround is to return a `mempool<> &` from a static member function.

```
template <class obj, class mthd>
class functor
{
private:
  static mempool<functor> & get_pool () {
    static mempool<functor> pool;
    return pool;
  }
};

//template <class obj, class mthd>
//mempool<functor<obj, mthd> > functor<obj, mthd>::pool;
```

This works because the reference means it is okay for `mempool<>` to remain incomplete until after `functor<>` is instantiated. (Actually, a method of a template is not instantiated unless there is code that actually calls it.) When the static method is called, `functor<>` itself is complete, so the static object within `functor<>::get_pool` can be properly instantiated.

> <sub>As a side note, it is acceptable to pass an incomplete type as an argument to a template, but the template has restrictions on what it can actually do with an incomplete type. Everything is fine if the template only requires a reference or pointer to the type for its instantiation.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `functor` is recursive. It requires the compiler to know the size of the type of `functor` while determining the `functor` type. You can generate exactly the same problem with this code:

```
template <class A>
class B {
public:
    static const int szA = sizeof(A);
};

template <class A>
class C {
public:
    static B<C<A> > b;
};

int main() {
    C<int> c;
}
```

Depending on what your application is, you should be able to do what you want using [type traits](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442).

Comment: I thought static data members would not contribute to the size of a class so there should not be any recursion here...

Comment: It doesn't matter what the size of the class will eventually be. At the point you're declaring the static member, the compiler doesn't know what the size of the class is because it hasn't finished declaring the class.

Answer (score 1):

At the time you declare `pool` *inside* of `functor`, you are still defining the `functor` class, so the type `functor` is still incomplete.

This is similar to forward declarations:

```
class functor;
functor func; <<-incomplete here
functor *ptr; <<-pointer is fine
class functor
{
    functor func; <<-incomplete again
}; 
functor func; <<-now complete definition, ok
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it, because you have a recursive definition. For example, you can't do this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

class B;

class A
{
    B b;
};

class B
{
    A a;
};

int main()
{
        A x;
}
```

The only way out is to make one of the members a pointer instead of an instance.